# Need help on Spring Security REST API plugin for grails

Tags: java, rest, grails, spring-security

I just faced the issue while using Spring Security REST API plugin for grails.
When I want to update some object of certain class. I then call the URL with PUT in it and the object which needed to updated.
But suppose I send the different object of different class, It still takes the id from there gets the object of required class and updates it.

Example: I want to update the test object, so I call /com/test with PUT and object of com.Test domain (this works great)
But if I call the same URL /com/test with object of com.Test123 domain, it then takes the id and gets the object of Test domain with the same id and updates it.
I don't need this. If the class doesn't match, it must show the class mismatch error.

Is it some configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

What is the wire format for your PUT request.

If it is JSON then the server will simply try and re-create your server side object from the JSON data. And so long as the signatures match the object will be unmarshalling without an error.

To get the sort of behavior you are looking for you need to use XML and JAXB. In this case the XML sent across will have enough info to ensure the correct class is created when unmarshalling.